# Calculating eigenvalue and normalised eigenvector due to multiple rotated Stern-Gerlach Apparatusses

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Suppose a beam of particles of spin 1/2 is incident on a Stern-Gerlach apparatus
aligned in the z-direction, which divides the beam into components with magnetic spin quantum numbers $m_s = 1/2$ . The $m_s = 1/2$ beam is incident on a Stern-Gerlach
apparatus aligned in the direction

$e_\theta = \begin{bmatrix}
           sin(\theta) \\
           0 \\
           cos(\theta)
         \end{bmatrix}
 $

Here I'm assuming that we work in the basis of $\hat S_z$. The spin operator $\hat S$ is represented by $(\hbar /2)\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the usual vector of Pauli matrices

**How do I find the eigenvalue and normalised eigenvectors of $e_\theta\cdot \hat S $ ?**

The first road block I stumble upon, is that I'm unsure how to even address the problem of taking the product of a $3\times1$ and a $2\times2$ matrix. Also am I correct in thinking that $\hat S$ in this case is simply $\sigma_z$ ?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue that appears when first learning about this, and what you have to do is separate the different types of vectors that are appearing. There are the "classical" vectors $e_{\theta}$ and $\vec{S}$ that have three components corresponding to three component directions in position space. Then there are the *state* vectors that live in an internal "spin" Hilbert space, and these are the vectors associated with Pauli matrices $\sigma_i$.

To be explicit, here's how I would write things down (leaving off factors of 2 and $\hbar$ and the like):
$$\vec{S} = \hat{x}\sigma_x + \hat{y}\sigma_y + \hat{z}\sigma_z,$$
and
$$\vec{e}_\theta = \hat{x}\sin\theta + \hat{y}(0)+ \hat{z}\cos\theta.$$
Then, the dot product $\vec{e}_\theta\cdot\vec{S}$ is interpreted to be the dot product of vectors in real space, and therefore
$$\vec{e}_\theta\cdot\vec{S} = \sigma_x\sin\theta + \sigma_y(0) + \sigma_x\cos\theta.$$
This last quantity is clearly a 2 by 2 matrix representation of a spin operator. You can look up the matrix representation of the Pauli operators written in the eigenbasis of $S_z$, and so you can get a matrix that you can diagonalize directly.

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up. An extension to that question, am I right in thinking that the intensity of the two beams would simply be the expectation value? If so. How would I determine $\psi$ ?